# Return clicked button id instead of (accept, reject flags) on QDialog- PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

### Summary:

I've been using QMessageBox in my application (for this purpose asking for saving project before closing, Error messages), And now I want to have a custom style (Custom title bar, custom buttons and so on), I found it is hard to do that with QMessageBox, And since I've been using a QDialog in my application as well (For this purpose: Taking input from user), I decided to use a custom QDialog (Make my own style on it) instead of QMessageBox for these all previous purpose, since it is easier to customize and creating my style.

### The problem:

The problem that I have now is: QDialog return only a flag value (0,1) depending on the button role And that's fine if I have only 2 buttons BUT here I have 3 (Save, Cancel, Close), Save will return 1 and both Close and Cancel return 0. And QMessageBox as I've seen it return the id of the Button that was clicked.

### An example (commented well hopefully :D):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class CustomDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Data will be lost")
        label = QLabel("Are you sure you want close the app before saving?")
        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox()
        buttonBox.addButton(QDialogButtonBox.Save)
        buttonBox.addButton(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.addButton(QDialogButtonBox.Close)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.resize(300, 100)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # These two lines, return 0 or 1.
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)    

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        label = QLabel('Hello Dialog', self)
        open_dialog_button = QPushButton('Open Dialog', self)
        open_dialog_button.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        open_message_box_button = QPushButton('Open Message Box', self)
        open_message_box_button.clicked.connect(self.show_message_box)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(open_dialog_button)
        layout.addWidget(open_message_box_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def showDialog(self):
        self.dialog = CustomDialog(self)
        btn_clicked = self.dialog.exec_()  # dialog exec returns 0 or 1 (Save = 1, Close and Cancel returns 0)

        # I want something like this.
        if btn_clicked == QDialogButtonBox.Save:
            print("Close.. After Saving...")
        elif btn_clicked == QDialogButtonBox.Close:
            print("Close.. Without saving")
        else:
            print("Cancel.. Don't exit the program")

    def show_message_box(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msg.setText("Are you sure you want close the app before saving?")
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Close | QMessageBox.Save | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        msg.setWindowTitle("Data will be lost")
        btn_clicked = msg.exec_()

        # Here i can do this.
        if btn_clicked == QMessageBox.Save:
            print("Close.. After Saving...")
        elif btn_clicked == QMessageBox.Close:
            print("Close.. Without saving")
        else:
            print("Cancel.. Don't exit the program")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.resize(200, 200)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution and it worked with me by using a custom signal and slot, but still not sure if it is good or not. waiting for approval and then I can mark this solution as an accepted one.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class CustomDialog(QDialog):
    # Create a signal
    signal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Data will be lost")
        label = QLabel("Are you sure you want close the app before saving?")
        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox()
        self.buttonBox.addButton(QDialogButtonBox.Save)
        self.buttonBox.addButton(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.buttonBox.addButton(QDialogButtonBox.Close)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        self.resize(300, 100)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # connect each button with custom slot
        self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Save).clicked.connect(lambda: self.customSlot(QDialogButtonBox.Save))
        self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Close).clicked.connect(lambda: self.customSlot(QDialogButtonBox.Close))
        self.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel).clicked.connect(lambda: self.customSlot(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel))

        # connect signal with buil-in function from QDialog (done())
        # This done function will return <int> value and close the dialog.
        self.signal.connect(self.done)

    def customSlot(self, button_id):
        # emit button's id
        self.signal.emit(button_id)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        label = QLabel('Hello Dialog', self)
        open_dialog_button = QPushButton('Open Dialog', self)
        open_dialog_button.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(open_dialog_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def showDialog(self):
        dialog = CustomDialog()
        btn_clicked = dialog.exec_()  # dialog exec returns button's id

        # Now you can use the following lines of code
        if btn_clicked == QDialogButtonBox.Save:
            print("Close.. After Saving...")
        elif btn_clicked == QDialogButtonBox.Close:
            print("Close.. Without saving")
        else:
            print("Cancel.. Don't exit the program")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.resize(200, 200)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Instead of using individual button signals and lambda, you can use [`buttonBox.clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#clicked) and in the slot emit the [`buttonBox.buttonRole(button)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#buttonRole).

Comment: @musicamante Thanks that will be better. Do you think there is a better solution, Or this one will be enough?

Comment: I find it conceptually correct, but there is one important aspect that must be considered: a QDialog's `exec` returns a [`DialogCode`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#DialogCode-enum) enum, for which `Accepted` is 1 and `Rejected` 0. QDialogButtonBox's [button roles](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#ButtonRole-enum) behave in the opposite way, with `AcceptRole` being 0 (the assumption is that any value != 0 should result in a different behavior than just accepting). This makes the return of your `exec()` a bit odd, as it's often assumed that `if dlg.exec():` means that the dialog ->

Comment: -> has been accepted. As long as you are completely aware of that, that's fine, but consider that you may return back to your code after some time (or somebody else could collaborate with you) and then the opposite behavior might not be considered/remembered. While it's common to use custom return values for a QDialog's `exec()`, it's normally better to keep the "conceptual" behavior (a truthfulness statement for an accepted dialog), so you may consider creating a custom attribute with a default state, and set it before closing the dialog, then access it after exec from the calling function.